# How to use grouped regex content from one file to another?

Tags: c#, regex

How do I get the matched regex group value from one file and paste it in a different file
I've tried something like this

```
var doc=File.ReadAllText(@"D:\Project\12345\database\xyz.txt");
            Regex r=new Regex(@"<ttl>(\w+)</ttl>");
            Match m=r.Match(doc);
            string gr=m.Groups[1].Value;
            File.WriteAllText(@"E:\Final\12345\2017\xyz.txt", File.ReadAllText(@"E:\Final\12345\2017\123.txt").Replace("<ce-title>[^<]+</ce-title>","<ce-title>"+gr+"</ce-title>"));
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.ReadLine();
```

But it does not work for some reason and I can't figure out what is wrong?
I'm basically trying to get content inside the first `<ttl>` element from one file and paste that value to another files `<ce-title>` element using regex.
NOTE: I'm aware that this can be done using xml/html parsing techniques but I want to know how I can do this simple thing using regex.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: But you are not using `Regex.Replace`, you are using a `String.Replace`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew How do I change my code to `Regex.Replace` in the above case?

Comment: `File.WriteAllText(@"E:\Final\12345\2017\xyz.txt", Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(@"E:\Final\12345\2017\123.txt"), "<ce-title>[^<]+</ce-title>",$"<ce-title>{gr}</ce-title>"));`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm getting an error **Unexpected character '$'**

Comment: You are using older C#, use `string.Format("<ce-title>{0}</ce-title>", gr)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `String.Replace()` rather than `Regex.Replace`.

Re-write your code as follows:

```
var doc=File.ReadAllText(@"D:\Project\12345\database\xyz.txt");
var r = new Regex(@"<ttl>(\w+)</ttl>");
Match m=r.Match(doc);
if (m.Success)
{
     var gr = m.Groups[1].Value;
     var rx = new Regex("<ce-title>[^<]+</ce-title>");
     File.WriteAllText(@"E:\Final\12345\2017\xyz.txt", 
          rx.Replace(
               File.ReadAllText(@"E:\Final\12345\2017\123.txt‌​"),  // Input
               string.Format("<ce-title>{0}</ce-title>", gr),     // Replacement
               1                                                  // Number of occurrences
          )
     );
}
Console.WriteLine("Done");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Since `gr` only consists of word chars, it is safe to use `string.Format("<ce-title>{0}</ce-title>", gr)` as a replacement. Else, if there is a need to support any chars, you need to use `string.Format("<ce-title>{0}</ce-title>", gr.Replace("$", "$$"))`.

Comment: Could you explain the use of `gr.Replace("$", "$$")`, what it is actually doing and how it works, I've never used anything like this before..

Comment: Also, how do I replace only the first found match using the above code, do I need to add **1** to `gr.Replace` function like `gr.Replace("$","$$"), 1`

Comment: @Bumba: `var rx = new Regex(....); var res=rx.Replace(s, with, numofoccurrences);`

Comment: But where do I put the `,1` in the above code? I'm confused.

Comment: Thanks. BTW you did not explain the `gr.Replace("$", "$$")`, also is it mandatory to use `string.Format` anyways?